# Interrupt function execution on key press

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, python-multithreading, interrupt

I am looking for a way to break out of a function and the loop that it is called in with some sort of interrupt. Ideally if the user presses a particular key the loop ends and the code goes back to asking the user for an input.

Pseudo code below...

```
def main():

    #main loop
    while True:

        #user asked to select an option
        inp = input()

        if inp == "option_1":
            #option 1 loop
            while True:
                perform_option1()
        
        elif inp == "option_2":
            #option 2 loop
            while True:
                perform_option2()

        elif inp == "quit":
            #exit the program
            exit()
```

Just to be clear the program asks the user for an input. Based on that input we move into one of two infinite loops. I am looking for a way to break these loops when the user presses a particular key and go back to the initial loop where the program will ask the user for an input again. I do not want to use input() or any other method where the code needs to stop and wait for input. I feel like this can be solved by threading or maybe a custom exception (no idea how to do that currently) and have read several other similar questions but can't for the life of me wrap my head around a way to make this work.

If possible I would love to use a standard library to accomplish this. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Use the 'currses' library

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) third party library, but you can use other libraries as well. I choosed `keyboard`. This library needs `sudo` privileges also.

`subthread` will listen for key `q`. If `q` was pressed, this `subthread` will send `SIGUSR1` signal to `mainthread`. mainthread has `SIGUSR1` handler, if `SIGUSR1` signal is send to `mainthread`, then `interrupted` func will be run by `mainthread`. `interrupted` func will raise `CancelException` exception, this exception will be handled by `mainthread` because we use `except CancelException` block.

If any exception occur in signal handler function when you are in `try` block, you can catch this exception, and handle this exception in `except` block

Below code is very simple example, you need to modify it your case:

```
import signal
import os
import keyboard
import time

from threading import Thread

class CancelException(Exception):
    pass

def interrupted(signum, frame):
    raise CancelException

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, interrupted)

def listen_for():
    keyboard.wait('q')
    print("q pressed")

    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGUSR1)

Thread(target=listen_for).start()

def f():
    while 1:
        print("1")
        time.sleep(1)

def g():
    while 1:
        print("2")
        time.sleep(1)

def main():
    #main loop
    while True:

        #user asked to select an option
        inp = input("give me an input: ")

        if inp == "1":
            while True:
                try:
                    f()
                except CancelException:
                    break
        elif inp == "2":
            while True:
                try:
                    g()
                except CancelException:
                    break


        elif inp == "quit":
            #exit the program
            exit()

main()
```